# Enumerate the WorkbookQuery Objects in an Excel WorkSHEET

Tags: excel, vba

Though I know how to enumerate (in VBA code) the WorkbookQuery objects in a whole Workbook, I need to know how to do so for just one sheet.  Here is the code that works for the whole Workbook...

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub EnumerateWorkbookQueries()

    Dim q As WorkbookQuery

    For Each q In ThisWorkbook.Queries
        Debug.Print q.Name
    Next q

End Sub
```

I understand that WorkbookQuery objects are (as the name implies) collected in the workbook, but the data they return goes into tables that are on specific worksheets.  When you click onto one of those tables, Excel knows to highlight its associated WorkbookQuery object in the Queries list (assuming the user has that open).

Comment: So, what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each Query displayed on a sheet, there is an automatically created Workbook scoped Name that referes to a ListObject, that displays the Query result (View them in the Name Manager).  Those `ListObject`'s have a `WorkbookConnection` property, whose name is *related* to the `Query` name.

If you have a Query named say `MyQuery` (displayed on a sheet)  there will be a ListObject whose WorkbookConnection is named `Query - MyQuery`.

If you look at the "Existing Connections" dialog in Excel, the connections are listed with the "Query - " prefix, but if you edit a connection, the name property is editable *without* that prefix. On commiting a name change the prefix is re-added automatically. Editing the name of a Query updates the WorkbookConnection name, and visa versa.

You can gear off this to check for Queries on any given sheet

```
Public Sub EnumerateWorksheetQueries(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim qt As QueryTable

    If ws.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
        For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
            Set qt = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
                Set qt = lo.QueryTable
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not qt Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print  ws.Parent.Queries(Mid$(lo.QueryTable.WorkbookConnection.Name, 9)).Name
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Call it somthing like this

```
Sub Demo1
    EnumerateWorksheetQueries ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

Or

```
Sub Demo2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print "Queries on " & ws.Name
        EnumerateWorksheetQueries ws
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: One gotcha, the default Name of the ListObject is also *related* to the Query, but can be changed by the user.  When a ListObject name is changed, the names of the Query and WorkbookConnection *do NOT* update.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you.  I tested your code. It worked after I addressed the "gotcha" you mentioned.  Specifically, every single query in my workbook caused a ListObject to be implemented whose name bore no resemblance to the query.  That's okay though!  It forced me to rename my queries intelligently, then go into Name Manager and give the corresponding ListObect items matching names.

I appreciate your explanation, and now I do wish there was a means of "running down" the corresponding ListObject other than matching on name.

Comment: I have extended your solution and ask that you review it and amend your answer if you see fit.  I changed Line 12 to: 
Debug.Print ws.Parent.Queries(Mid(lo.QueryTable.WorkbookConnection.Name, 9, 99)).Name

That worked better because the workbook connection name was reliably "Query - [Whatever the query name was]."

Comment: @John I can't find any better way to identify the relationship between `Query`'s and `ListObject`s / `Connections`'s.  All of them may be renamed by the user, so my answer and your alternative are vulnerable to that.  Bottom line: I don't think the Power Query Object Model is complete

Comment: unless I'm mistaken, the user can rename the ListObject (in Name Manager) and the Query all they want, but my minor tweak to your code will still match them up.  I've implemented it and tested it.  I'd really like to mark your answer as the answer, as I never could have gotten "there" without it.  Please consider testing my tweak and updating your answer.

Comment: @John You're right, great find!  `WorkbookConnection` and `Query` names are related, and tied together, so that mod is rubust.

Comment: Hi Chris. Could you tell where the "Existing Connections" dialog is present in Excel. I only see 'Queries and Connections" button under "Data", which by the way doesn't have the prefix you mentioned.