# VBA: How to delete Queries from active worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Workbook that has a "live" tab, which has around 8 Queries.

Everyday I duplicate this sheet, before refreshing. In the duplicated sheet, I would like to remove all queries, as i dont need them anymore.

I'm trying to create a macro to remove all Queries.

I tried following code, but it doesn't work. error:  `object doesn't support this method` for the line 5.

```
Sub DelQueries()
    Dim q As WorkbookQuery
   
    For Each q In ActiveWorkbook.Queries
        If q.Parent.Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then
            q.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I also tried the code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827417/delete-a-query-from-excel-workbook-with-vba), with some modification, but gets syntax error for line  3.

```
Sub loop_del_query()
For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Worksheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Name
        Qcount = Worksheet.Queries.Count
        If Qcount > 0 Then
            For Each Query In Worksheet.Queries
                Query.Delete
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next Worksheet
End Sub
```

Comment: In your 2nd code, the `If`-statement misses the `Then`

Comment: The parent of a WorkbookQuery is the Queries collection which is a property of a  Workbook not a Worksheet. Do you want to remove all queries in the workbook ?

Comment: @CDP1802 No, I need to remove all queries in the current worksheet

Comment: Do you mean all queries that show results on the current worksheet ?

Comment: @CDP1802 yes, any query that populates data on the current worksheet

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043222/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043222/) try ;

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteQueries()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim wq As WorkbookQuery, qname As String
    Dim qt As QueryTable, tbl As ListObject
    Dim msg As String, dict As Object
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' existing queries
    For Each wq In wb.Queries
        dict.Add wq.Name, 1
    Next
    
    ' scan table object for query tables
    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
        Set qt = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set qt = tbl.QueryTable
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not qt Is Nothing Then
            qname = qt.WorkbookConnection.Name
            If Left(qname, 8) = "Query - " Then
                qname = Mid(qname, 9)
                'Debug.Print tbl.Name & " Query:" & qname
                 
                'delete query if exists
                If dict.exists(qname) Then
                    wb.Queries(qname).Delete
                    msg = msg & vbCrLf & qname
                Else
                    Debug.Print "Not found", qname
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    If msg = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Queries deleted", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Queries deleted:" & msg, vbInformation
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I notice that the script above only works alternatively. Background: the sheet that im deleting queries from is generated everyday (from a master, as a copy). So if one time i run this it works, then running the second time (after regenerating the copy again) it doesn't remove the queries. Any idea why ?